# dynamically add remove rows in table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have construted my table as follows:

```
    <table id="dataTable">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Name</th>
               <th>Value</th></tr>
            </thead>
<TR><TD>Scooby Doo</TD><TD>6</TD><TD><INPUT TYPE="Button"  onClick="AddRow()" VALUE="Add Row"></TD></TR>
</table>
```

When the button Add Row is clicked, I need to change the button to a delete button and insert a new row on the first line.  The first line must contain the same  as in the code.  How can I do this?

On clicking the delete button,  Imust be able to delete the row to which the delete button belong?

Answer (score 8):

Hope this helps

```
$(function(){
  $("input[type='button'].AddRow").toggle(
     function(){
       var el = $(this);
       el.closest('tr').clone(true).prependTo(el.closest('table'));
       el.attr("value", "Delete row");
     },
     function(){ 
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();          
  });
});

<table id="dataTable" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Value
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Scooby Doo
        </td>
        <td>
            6
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="Button" value="Add Row" class="AddRow">
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/arete3)**

Answer (score 1):

Something like?

```
$('#dataTable thead').prepend('<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>');
```

And for the deleting:

```
$('#dataTable thead tr').click(function() {
$(this).hide(); //hide the row, this doesn't delete it.
});
```

.