# A way to add to a table on the fly that could have the values removed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dynamically add remove rows in table using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228772/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-table-using-jquery)

I've been trying to google demos of this but have no idea on how to word it.

I'd like to be able to have textboxes that require information. When you click add (next to the textboxeS) it populates a table below that stores the information. The more you add the longer the table is. You can also delete the values in the table.

What would i need to do that? Are there any examples of what this is called?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2228927/952310

Comment: @Den You should really include an example, especially since you have a problem wording your requirements. You probably don't want to share your production example, but think of a parallel example that shares the same idea. Usually cars are a great concept, because everyone understands make, model, year and the such.

Comment: Or Google "jquery dynamically add form elements"

Comment: This sentence is confusing 'When you click add it populates a table below that stores information.' Do you mean it CREATES a row in the table below the textboxes? Or that the textboxes are within the table so a new row is CREATED containing the new textboxes?

Comment: @da5id Thank you. That was exactly what i was talking about. Found a demo here http://papermashup.com/demos/dynamic-form/