# adding and removing rows to and from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add and remove rows to and from this table at the end how can i achieve this

```
<table align="left" id="postq" style="display: none;" border="2" style="width: 519px">
    <tr>
    <th align="left"><label id="Label1"> Kind of Work </label></th>
    <th align="left"><label id="Label1"> Name Of The Client </label></th>
    <th align="left"><label id="Label1">Name of Firm / Organisation </label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> 
    <input title="Enter Kind Of work 1" readonly="readonly" onclick="if(this.value!=''){this.value='';opendrop1();}else{opendrop1();}" id="other_work1" name="other_work1" type="text" size="30" <?php if (isset($errors)) { echo 'value="'.htmlentities($_POST['other_work1']).'"'; } ?>  >                
    </td>                       
     <td><input name="client_name1" type="text" id="client_name1" size="40" /></td>
     <td><input name="firm_name1" type="text" id="firm_name1" size="40"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

i have added this script

```
 <!--add kind of work rows-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
     var counter = 2;
    $("#addButton").click(function () {

                if (counter > 10) {
                    alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
                    return false;
                }            
                var $row = $('<tr>');//$('<tr id="row'+counter+'"></tr>')
            $row.html('<td><input title="Enter Kind Of work " readonly="readonly" onclick="if(this.value!=''){this.value='';opendrop();}else{opendrop();}" id="other_work' + counter + '" name="other_work' + counter + '" type="text" size="30" onclick="opendrop()"  <?php if (isset($errors)) { echo 'value="'.htmlentities(@$_POST['other_work' + counter + '']).'"'; } ?>> </td>
     <td><input name="client_name' + counter + '" type="text" id="client_name' + counter + '" size="40"/></td>
     <td><input name="firm_name' + counter + '" type="text" id="firm_name' + counter + '" size="40"/></td>');
     $('#postq').append($row);
                counter++;
            });
    </script>
```

and this button but still it is not working

```
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton' />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228772/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-table-using-jquery

Comment: no that is not useful to me ,i want to add and remove at the end of table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add row at last:

```
$('#postq > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>Added here</td></tr>');
```

To remove row at last:

```
$('#postq > tbody:last tr:last').remove();
```

Comment: when i use your line of code than row is getting added but when i use it like this `$('#preq > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input title="Enter Kind Of work new" readonly="readonly" onclick="if(this.value!=''){this.value='';opendrop();}else{opendrop();}" id="other_work5" name="other_work5" type="text" size="30" onclick="opendrop()"  <?php if (isset($errors)) { echo 'value="'.htmlentities(@$_POST['other_workn']).'"'; } ?>></td><td><input name="client_name5" type="text" id="client_name5" size="40"/></td><td><input name="firm_name5" type="text" id="firm_name5"size="40"/></td></tr>');`not working

Answer (score 1):

To add a row:

```
$('#postq>tbody')
    .append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>')
            .text('cell 1 text'))
        .append($('<td>')
            .text('cell 2 text')));
```

To remove a row:

```
$('#postq>tbody>tr').remove();
```

Comment: I HAVE EDITED CODE LIKE THIS BUT IT IS NOT WORKING $('#preq>tbody')
.append($('<tr>').append($('<td>').text('<input title="Enter Kind Of work " readonly="readonly" onclick="if(this.value!='')this.value='';opendrop();}else{opendrop();}" id="other_work' + counter + '" name="other_work' + counter + '" type="text" size="30" onclick="opendrop()"  <?php if (isset($errors)) { echo 'value="'.htmlentities(@$_POST['other_work' + counter + '']).'"'; } ?>>'))
        .append($('<td>')
            .text('<input name="client_name' + counter + '" type="text" id="client_name' + counter + '" size="40"/>')));

Comment: You are breaking the string with unescaped single quotes at `.text('<input ... onclick="if(this.value!='')...')`. You need to escape them like so: `.text('<input ... onclick="if(this.value!=\'\')...')`.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#postq tr:last').remove()` would remove the last row.

`$('<tr class="yournewrow" />').insertAfter('#postq tr:last');` would allow you to insert a new row as the last in the table.